# Download data from website after selecting dropdowns and searching

Tags: batch-file, web, download

I am not a pure programmer but have good basic knowledge of programming. I am trying to automate a data download process (from a website) which I have to do every month. Following is the website which I have to use:

http://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/prelimdownload/searchLoad.action

If you go to the link you will see 2 dropdowns and one button. If you select state from dropdown 1. Then you select the updated counties from dropdown 2. Then you search by pressing the button 3. The page refreshes and you see a lot of download links. If you scroll down to the bottom you will see "FIRM Database" and a download link for the zip file. I want to download this for all the states for all the counties. Can someone please suggest me the easiest way and the scripting language I should use for this. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: What scripting language you use is up to you. However, if you want a screenscaping tutorial you are probably in the wrong forum. There are lot of people here who will be willing to help you when you have a specific, programming related problem, but very few who will spend time writing introduction courses or tutorials for you. Start by read up a bit, try coding, and come back when you get stuck!

Comment: Right click each link - Copy Shortcut - them paste into Notepad. Add this to beginning of link `http://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/prelimdownload/`. Just put into a batch file with `iexplore` before. `iexplore http://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/prelimdownload/prelim/ProductsDownLoadServlet?pfiProdId=24998` and you'll get a prompt to Open or Save. See my post here how to download silently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275797/download-file-from-dynamic-link-using-vbscript-or-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the download link for a `FIRM Database` you can see that you have
the `state Name` and the `county name` as arguments.

example with Alabama -> Montgomery County :

http://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/prelimdownload/prelim/ProductsDownLoadServlet?pfiProdId=12996&stateName=Alabama&countyName=Montgomery%20County

So you can create a txt file with all the possibilities (ID State an county) like this :

```
29447,Massachusetts,Bristol County
12996,Alabama,Montgomery County
32516,New Mexico,Otero County
```

and make a BAT file who get's the value in the TXT file et reconstruct the link :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('type aaaa.txt') do (
set "$ID=%%a"
set "$State=%%b"
set "$County=%%c"
echo !$ID!
echo !$State!
echo !$County: =%%20!
start http://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/prelimdownload/prelim/ProductsDownLoadServlet?pfiProdId=!$ID!^&stateName=!$state: =%%20!^&countyName=!$County: =%%20!
)
```

With this solution you have to confirm with OK all the downloads. To contourn this problem you can use a command line tool like [WGET](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). In this case just replace the :

```
start http://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/prelimdownload/prelim/ProductsDownLoadServlet?pfiProdId=!$ID!^&stateName=!$state: =%%20!^&countyName=!$County: =%%20!
```

with :

```
wget http://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/prelimdownload/prelim/ProductsDownLoadServlet?pfiProdId=!$ID!^&stateName=!$state: =%%20!^&countyName=!$County: =%%20!
```

Or you can use @noodles his VBS solution to download silently : [Download file from dynamic link using VBScript or Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275797/download-file-from-dynamic-link-using-vbscript-or-powershell)

For a full automatic solution (without txt file) who will get the link automatically in the Source code of the WEB page. Use another scripting language.

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much. Will try this out next time I have to download.